# Динамический массив объектов C#

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть свой класс (public class MyNum). Как объявить, а потом инициализировать двумерный динамический массив, с объектами моего класса?

Как ни пробую, ошибки. Как делаю:

```
public MyNum [][] Array1= new MyNum[2][];
```

Далее пытаюсь так:

```
Array1[0][0]=new MyNum(arg1);
```

Естественно получаю крит, потому что под элемент массива `Array[0][0]` не выделена память. Казалось бы Всё должно облегчить `Array1[0].Append()`

Но так тоже не работает.

Как использовать динамические массивы?

**Доп вопрос**
В чем разница между объявлениями:

```
public MyNum[,] Array1; 
public MyNum[][] Array1;
```

не понимаю и нигде об этом не написано. Как обычно!!!

Comment: Динамические - это явно не про массивы. Используйте коллекции.

Comment: вы создали матрицу, но не создали Array1[0]

Comment: на питоне что-ли раньше писали? Массивы редко когда нужны, используйте типизированные коллекции.

Comment: я ничего не понимаю, и только учусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю, под динамическим массивом имеется ввиду именно тот, который можно изменять по ходу работы программы. Добавлять элементы, удалять элементы.
В шарпе таким "массивом" является List. (судя по вопросу, ты перешел с питона потому так неправильно и выражаюсь)

List является враппером (оберткой) вокруг Array. В джаве и некоторых других языках это называется ArrayList, что более соответствует тому, чем он является на самом деле. При желании ты можешь загуглить как именно он устроен.

Что именно тебе нужно - это создать лист листов.

```
var list = List<List<MyNum>>();
```

тогда же ты можешь использовать его так как тебе нужно.

```
list.add( new List<MyNum>() ); // добавляем строку
list[0].add( new MyNum(2) );   // добавляем ячейку в строку
```

и обращаться к нужной ячейке после этого

```
var myNum = list[0][0];
```

Использование же именно массивов для данного случая является нежелательным т.к. функция аппенд() по-факту является пересозданием массива в новой области памяти с размером на +1 ячейку с последующим копированием данных. Так что эта операция достаточно дорогостоящая по ресурсам и ее нужно избегать.

Конкретно массивы нужно использовать исключительно в том случае, если тебе наперед известно сколько именно элементов будет записано и их количество изменятся не будет.

---

Если же хочется использовать именно массив, то нужно сделать тот же подход что я сделал с листом. Сначала аппендить "строку под ячейки", а лишь потом уже аппендить ячейку в строку.

Comment: Наверное, вернусь к С++ ... Тяжко идёт шарп. Хотя и призван облегчить черновую работу!!!  Один include чего стоит в cpp

Comment: Шарп значительно проще плюсов. И значительно безопаснее. Меньшая возможность допустить ошибки, которые приведут к всякого рода утечкам, невозможно затупить со ссылками на переменные и многими другими плюшками) Все не так страшно как кажется. Хотя, как по мне, то есть и много откровенно гадостных синтаксических особенностей... Но, подозреваю, что их значительно меньше, чем в плюсах.

Comment: с++ вполне может быть безопасным при правильном владении, если ввести опрератор [] можно проверять на выход за пределы массива. При соблюдении нескольких правил - с++ показывает вполне приемлемый результат (тот же assert).  c# больше нужен для iis-web-сервера, или для кросс-птатформы - там, для планшета который в супермаркете который читает ШКИ товаров, или других целей. Да, c# применяется в desktop, но я считаю что плюсы в desktop гораздо сильнее, особено там где нужна мексимальная скорость.

Comment: с# проще для новичков тем, что например не нужно обьяснять что нельзя выходить за предел массива. с# даст явную ошибку, а плюсы будут "странно глючить". В c# проще так же тем, что если вы используте https или что-то ещё такое извесное - оно уже есть в коробке. У плюсов "в коробе" чуть меньше возможности.

Answer (score 0):

При выполнении данного кода

```
public MyNum [][] Array1= new MyNum[2][];
```

в `Array1` будет два элемента `null`. Именно поэтому при попытке обратиться к `Array1[0][0]` происходит ошибка.

Для того чтобы это заработало, перед обращением к конкретному элементу нужно создать данный массив, например:

```
Array1[0] = new MyNum[2]();
```

Тогда строчка `Array1[0][0]=new MyNum(arg1);` уже не будет давать ошибку.

---

Также можно сразу инициализировать массив, например:

```
new MyNum[2][] { new[] { new MyNum() }, new[] { new MyNum() } };
```

---

Если количество заранее неизвестно, либо может изменяться в процессе выполнения, можно воспользоваться `List<T>`. В нем присутствует операция `Add` для добавления новых элементов.

Comment: Array1[0] = new MyNum[2]();   не работает. "Требуется имя метода".  Скорее всего буду инициализировать в процессе работы. И вернусь к С++

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, где ты это пытался вызвать?

Comment: В Visual studio 19. Сильно далеко после объявления. Я по-другому сделал: Array1 = new MyNum[2, primernoekolich]; Вычислил примерное количество элементов, точно превышающее необходимое и инициализировал. Костыли, но работает.

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, делаешь неправильно :)

Comment: А как тогда? Я даже разницы между public MyNum[,] Array1; и public MyNum[][] Array1; не понимаю и нигде об этом не написано. Как обычно!!!

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, написано же [многомерные массивы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) и [зубчатые массивы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, можно обзор по массивам прочитать: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Comment: Читал. Даже учебник полистал. Но досконального, как для С++ на пару тысяч листов не нашёл. На торрентах не искал еще.

Comment: @СаакШахламджян, зачем нужны торренты  если есть отличная справка от микрософта?

Comment: по справке довольно сложно изучить многопоточность... Очень сухо и мало информации. MSDN по cpp был лучше. И по WinAPI тоже. Нет полного учебника, развернутого, разжеванного, полностью раскрывающего язык С#. А С++ очень много всего. 1-2 примера на сложнейшие конструкции, да еще и без полных комментариев полезно когда уже базис есть по языку. А если нет...